# "AADSTS50097: Device authentication" is required error during OAuth 2.0 device authorization grant flow

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, adal

I am trying to login into an Azure KeyVault using the OAuth device authorization grant flow but it gives me the following exception.

AADSTS50097: Device authentication is required.

A few more things
- I can access the said Keyvault through my browser
- This is device independent. I tested it on three separate devices
- Happened to another user who had recently changed his password

Any leads are appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please tell me if you can process Azure AD auth on other devices?

Comment: Hi Jim, I don't understand your question completely. I am able to access Azure portal through web browser on any device. But when I try to login using OAuth device authorization grant flow I first get this message
Message: To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code **** to authenticate, then I get this message in my browser
You have signed in to the Microsoft Azure PowerShell application on your device. You may now close this window. 
But then I get the exception Unhandled exception. AADSTS50097: Device authentication is required.